# ssh linux to windows fails, Connection reset

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sshd

I have set up the sshd server in windows 11 as in the official documentation. I have transfered my public key to the windows machine to C:\ProgramData\ssh\ as administrators_authorized_keys and changed the permission like it is written in the documentation:

Get the public key file generated previously on your client
$authorizedKey = Get-Content -Path $env:USERPROFILE.ssh\id_ed25519.pub

Generate the PowerShell to be run remotely that will copy the public key file generated previously on your client to the authorized_keys file on your server

Add-Content -Force -Path $env:ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys -Value "$authorizedKey"; icacls.exe "$env:ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r /grant "Administrator:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"

Also I have uncommented the sshd_config file line in C:\ProgramData\ssh\ and set to PubkeyAuthentication yes

still I can´t connect. It is hanging for about 2 seconds then the connection breaks with the error: Connection reset by 192.168.2.132 port 22

this is the output of the debug message:

```
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
ls
Connection reset by 192.168.2.132 port 22
```

Comment: The next thing that should happen after SERVICE_ACCEPT is "userauth none" resulting in "Authentications that can continue:" and then usually a 'real' userauth. See if the server (sshd) has logged anything; on Windows this is in the Windows eventlog accessible by EventViewer; on my system (at least) it is in a folder OpenSSH under Applications and Services Logs .